# How to prevent ENTER Key on Buttons

Tags: mfc

I have a CFormView Dialog with Buttons to send commands for a hardware I/O.
I the user accidentally click the enter key, the command is executed. (the last button one, that has the focus).

How do you solve this in the correct way?

Answer (score 0):

The way ist to use PreTranslateMessage. CHeck for WM_KEYDOWN and VK_ENTER. Ignore it or do whatever you want.

Background: CFormView::PreTranslateMessage later calls PreTranslateInput and this finally calls IsDialogMessage and this functions translates the Enter key to execute the default dialog button.

Comment: There are CEdit controls too. Is this solution impact free on existing CEdit controls?

Comment: Feel free to check what control has the focus. On a button simply ignore it. In more detail you can check the window class type of the window that has the focus.... and ignore the message or let it be handled. If PreTranslateMessage gets a VK_ENTER the reaction in an edit control depends on the dialog code it send back...

Comment: Thx, that works. Unfortunatelly I have still problem with the (Afx)MessageBoxes. The user can accidentaly click it away with Enter Key too. I think I have to write my own MessageBoxes with the mentioned PreTranslateMessage.

Comment: @TomTom: You could install a [WH_GETMESSAGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx#whgetmessagehook) hook on the calling thread, and intercept the `WM_KEYDOWN` message for the enter key. You can modify this message (e.g. by setting it to `WM_NULL`), which nullifies the effect. This allows you to deal with (Afx)MessageBoxes.